# how to make an encoded string in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I want to make my string like `"abc 123 def"` to be `"abc%20123%20def"`
so can use it as query parameter in my http request like this

```
https://myBaseUrl.com?parameter=abc%20123%20def"
```

how to do that ?

I have tried using this

```
val myString = "321 pop"
val enCodedString  = URLEncoder.encode(myString, "utf-8")
```

but if I print, it will produce string like this `"321+pop"`

Java or Kotlin are OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected behavior for encoding the space character. If you want to replace the `+` with the percent encoding, do

```
System.out.println(java.net.URLEncoder.encode("Hello World", "UTF-8").replace("+", "%20"));
```